# Regex python do lookahead in a conditional statement

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do lookaheads in a conditional statement.
Explanation by words:

`(specified string that has to be a number (decimal or not) or a word character, a named capturing group is created) (if the named capturing group is a word character then check if the next string is a number (decimal or not) with a lookahead else check if the next string is a word character with a lookahead)`

To understand, here some examples that are matched or not:

`a 6` or `6.4 b`-> matched, since the first and the second string haven't the same "type"

`ab 7` or `7 rt` -> not matched, need only a single word character

`R 7.55t` -> not matched, 7.55t is not a valid number

`a r` or `5 6`-> not matched, the first and the second string have the same "type" (number and number, or, word character and word character)

I've already found the answer for the first string: `(?P<var>([a-zA-Z]|(-?\d+(.\d+)?)))`

I've found nothing on Internet about lookaheads in a condition statement in Python.

The problem is that Python doesn't support conditional statement like PCRE:

Python supports conditionals using a numbered or named capturing group. Python does not support conditionals using lookaround, even though Python does support lookaround outside conditionals. Instead of a conditional like `(?(?=regex)then|else)`, you can alternate two opposite lookarounds: `(?=regex)then|(?!regex)else`. (source: https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

Maybe there's a better solution that I've planned or maybe it's just impossible to do what I want, I don't know.

What I tried: `(?P<var>([a-zA-Z]|(-?\d+(.\d+)?))) (?(?=[a-zA-Z])(?=(-?\d+(.\d+)?))|(?=[a-zA-Z]))(?P=var)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Your exposition is kind of messy. It's not clear why you _require_ a solution with lookaheads and conditionals. `(?P<number1>[\d.]+)\s+(?P<char1>\w(?!\w)|(?P<char2>\w(?!\w))\s+(?P<number2>[\d.]+)` would match both cases and give you named groups which indicate what exactly was matched.

Comment: `\w` includes numerics and my float expression is obviously sloppy. Perhaps [edit] your question to clarify these things.

Comment: It's not mandatory to use lookaheads and conditionals, that's just how I approach the problem.

Comment: Your regex has an error, and when I added the missing paranthesis, the regex doesn't match what I asked. You do not have to use lookaheads, conditional statements or/and capturing groups. If there is another way to do it without that I am interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named capture group `(?P<var>...)` contains the actual text which matched, not the regex itself. There is a way to create a named regex, too; but it's probably not particularly necessary or useful here.

Simply spell out the alternatives:

`((?<![a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z]\s+-?\d+(.\d+)?(?![a-zA-Z.0-9])|(?<![a-zA-Z.0-9])-?\d+(.\d+)?\s+[a-zA-Z](?![a-zA-Z0-9]))`

If you genuinely require the second token to remain unmatched, it should be obvious how to change the parts starting at each `\s` into a lookahead.

Demo: https://ideone.com/nPNAIN